# Jquery image gallery: performance issue

Tags: jquery

My client needs a photo gallery for his website. However, he will be uploading at least a few hundreds of pictures with time.

I have found Galleryview as a great plugin to suit my needs, but I realize that images are all preloaded, which is not suitable for hundreds of pictures. Do you have any ideas how I could get this plugin to load only the images in the displayed thumbnails instead?

Or is there a pluggin better suited for my needs?

http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/

Comment: I eventually ended up writing my own - got PHP to create the thumbs, and Javascript / jQuery to do necessary preloading... :/

Comment: @ChrisKempen But even then, not all images will be the same width and height...

Comment: Of course not...you'll probably want to scale them to a maximum width / height using [PHP's GD functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), but this is bordering on a different set of questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery cycle plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

I used this for creating a slideshow for my current project and it works fine.  You build a `<ul />` of images and than the slideshow will cycle through them.  This allows you to define exactly what images you want loaded.

[image: Example of my project]